# Register a User and Let the user login using Typo3

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm new to TYPO3, I want to insert a registration form to my home page and let the registered users view a specific page (Lessons)

I tried to implement the form module but I could not find a way to integrate it. This is the YAML code which is generated.

```
renderingOptions:
  submitButtonLabel: Register
type: Form
identifier: userRegistration
label: 'User Registration'
prototypeName: standard
finishers:
  -
    options:
      pageUid: '23'
      additionalParameters: ''
    identifier: Redirect
  -
    options:
      message: 'You have sucessgully registered with the course'
    identifier: Confirmation
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'Previous step'
      nextButtonLabel: 'Next step'
    type: Page
    identifier: page-1
    label: Step
    renderables:
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: Reg_email
        label: Email
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            required: required
            placeholder: Email
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
          -
            identifier: EmailAddress
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Password
        identifier: Reg_password
        label: Password
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            required: required
            placeholder: Password
            minlength: '8'
            maxlength: '100'
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
          -
            identifier: Alphanumeric
          -
            options:
              minimum: '8'
              maximum: '100'
            identifier: StringLength
```

I want to know, how to configure this form and how to use the registration data in the user login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namaste Muditha,

I'd recommend to use an extension which provides a user registration form and even a "user is logged in after successful registration" action.

Have a look at femanager: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/femanager/

The form you use is for simple forms like contact form or similar. User registration has way more complexity.

Comment: True. Will try it. It looks like it's better if we try Not to have a direct access with the DB with custom php, isn't it ? Thank you for the tip.